# Как только из первого выводимого списка удалить все повторяющиеся элементы (названия планет)?

Tags: java, list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HW3 {
    private static Object removeDuplicates;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        planetsCounter(8);
    }

    static void randomNumbers(int size, int maxValue) {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>(size);
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            nums.add(rand.nextInt(maxValue));

        for (Integer num : nums)
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        System.out.println();

        nums.sort(null);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = nums.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
    }

    static void planetsCounter(int n) {
        List<String> listPlanets = List.of("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus",
                "Neptun");
        List<String> randPlanets = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        int[] counts = new int[listPlanets.size()];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            randPlanets.add(listPlanets.get(rand.nextInt(listPlanets.size())));
            System.out.print((randPlanets.get(i)) + " ");
            counts[listPlanets.indexOf(randPlanets.get(i))]++;
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)

            System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", listPlanets.get(i), counts[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы действительно хотите _удалить_ дубликаты, из списка `randPlanets`?  Если да, то зачем вы их туда добавляете, ведь логичнее тогда использовать `Set` вместо `List`. Или вам нужно, чтобы дубликаты просто не выводились на печать?

Comment: И зачем в вашем коде неиспользуемый метод `randomNumbers` и неиспользуемая переменная `removeDuplicates`?  Постарайтесь предоставить [**минимальный** пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и объясните вашу проблему.

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, нужно просто чтобы дубликаты не выводились на печать. А что касается не используемых методов, то это учебная задача, я ее со всех сторон ее пытаюсь решить.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса - `Как только из первого выводимого списка удалить все повторяющиеся элементы (названия планет)`, какого списка?

Comment: Нашел решение сам                                                                                                            
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(randPlanets);
        randPlanets.clear();
        randPlanets.addAll(set);

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class HW3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        planetsCounter(8);
    }

    static void randomNumbers(int size, int maxValue) {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>(size);
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            nums.add(rand.nextInt(maxValue));

        for (Integer num : nums)
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        System.out.println();

        nums.sort(null);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = nums.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
    }

    static void planetsCounter(int n) {
        List<String> listPlanets = List.of("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus",
                "Neptun");
        List<String> randPlanets = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        int[] counts = new int[listPlanets.size()];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            randPlanets.add(listPlanets.get(rand.nextInt(listPlanets.size())));
            System.out.print((randPlanets.get(i)) + " ");
            counts[listPlanets.indexOf(randPlanets.get(i))]++;
        }

        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(randPlanets);
        randPlanets.clear();
        randPlanets.addAll(set);

        System.out.println(randPlanets);

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)

            System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", listPlanets.get(i), counts[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Этот код всё равно выводит _список с дубликатами_, список без дубликатов, и содержимое массива с частотами.

Comment: Да, но список с дубликатами всегда можно убрать, оставил для наглядности.